# Number theory proof with integers

Tags: number-theory

There is a positive integer n. Let's consider all numbers $\left\lfloor{n\over k}\right\rfloor$ where $k$ is a positive integer. Demonstrate that there are no more than $2\sqrt{n}+1$ such numbers that are different from each other.
Note: For a real number $x,$ by $\lfloor x\rfloor$ we mean the largest integer not greater than $x.$

For the context I'm a highschool student and I got this question from my teacher but I have no idea how to solve this.

If k>n then $\left\lfloor{n\over k}\right\rfloor$ will be equal to 0. So if k ∈ {1,...,n} then number of possible fractions will be smaller than $2\sqrt{n}$
I also concluded that it can't be more than n+1 unique fractions, but i have no idea how to make much headway on it.

I made a simple program to analyse data and this is the output:
1 unique fraction for 1 number ( 0 )
2 unique fractions for 1 number ( 1 )
3 unique fractions for 2 numbers ( 2 3 )
4 unique fractions for 2 numbers ( 4 5 )
5 unique fractions for 3 numbers ( 6 7 8 )
6 unique fractions for 3 numbers ( 9 10 11 )
7 unique fractions for 4 numbers ( 12 13 14 15 )
8 unique fractions for 4 numbers ( 16 17 18 19 )
9 unique fractions for 5 numbers ( 20 21 22 23 24 )
10 unique fractions for 5 numbers ( 25 26 27 28 29 )
11 unique fractions for 6 numbers ( 30 31 32 33 34 35 )
12 unique fractions for 6 numbers ( 36 37 38 39 40 41 )
13 unique fractions for 7 numbers ( 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 )
14 unique fractions for 7 numbers ( 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 )
15 unique fractions for 8 numbers ( 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 )
16 unique fractions for 8 numbers ( 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 )
17 unique fractions for 9 numbers ( 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 )
18 unique fractions for 9 numbers ( 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 )
19 unique fractions for 10 numbers ( 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 )
20 unique fractions for 10 numbers ( 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 )
and so on.

I think it's possible to create a formula for fractions count for integer n, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Did you mean $\lfloor \frac nk\rfloor$ where you wrote $\frac nk$?

Comment: Yes I meant [n/k]. Sorry for my typo.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: The answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363392/to-find-a-sum-of-ifloor2019-i-floor2019-i-1-i-range-from-2-to-2019/3363522#3363522 will give you the idea.

Comment: Seems that there are $n$ distinct values when $k = 1$.

Comment: @EricTowers $n$ is fixed, not $k$

Comment: @Sil : Exactly, so the claim should hold when $k = 1$.

Comment: @EricTowers - The claim is $\left|\{\lfloor \frac nk\rfloor \mid k \in \Bbb N_+\}\right| \le 2\sqrt n + 1$. $k$ is a dummy variable. Konrad Bal - Consider the values of $k$ where $\lfloor \frac nk\rfloor$ is different from $\lfloor \frac n{k-1}\rfloor$. When does this occur?

Comment: @PaulSinclair : Maybe that's the intended order of quantifiers.  But I'm not convinced that the question, as currently written, unambiguously communicates this.